# Filter KPIs on a Scorecard in PerformancePoint based on User

Tags: security, sharepoint, performancepoint

I would like to filter the KPIs shown on a scorecard by the user logged in to SharePoint.  Is this possible?

#### Requirements:

1. I have several users who own different KPIs
2. I am developing the performance management app in PerformancePoint planning.
3. I **don't** want to create multiple scorecards for each user as this could run into a lot of reports...
4. I want to direct all the users to **one** scorecard but it will only show them the relevant KPIs based on the logged in user.
5. Scorecards will be hosted in MOSS 2007

How can I set this up in PerformancePoint?

Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on the data source. What is the data source ?

Answer (score 1):

If you create one scorecard with all the kpis on there, and only grant access on the KPI level, you'll get a barebones approach to what you want.  The data for each KPI that a user does not have access to will show as blank.